# Question regarding upper and lower integral sums

Tags: real-analysis

[image]

This is from Binmore’s Mathematical analysis. My question is why does the author say that use of the second definition gives (7) with the negative signs. Second definition is depicted in figure 2. Also how does he say that (6) and (7) are equal? I’m afraid I’m missing something obvious. Is the negative sign due to the fact that the upper sum values go above the graph and we talk about area under the curve?

Answer (score 1):

It boils down to the property that $\sup a =-\inf (-a)$ for $a$ in some domain.

The upper integral is  defined as $\inf U(f,P)$, where $P$ is a partition of the interval.

This is equal to

$\inf \sum(\sup f(x)\cdot \Delta x) \\
= -\sup [-\sum(\sup f(x)\cdot \Delta x] \\
= -\sup [\sum(\inf (-f(x))\cdot \Delta x] \\
= -\sup L(-f,P)$,

which is $-\int_a^b -f(x)dx$ by the first definition via supremum.

As for the equality between (6) and (7), has the book introduced the fundamental theorem of calculus at this point yet?